# Is "Rotenstrand" a correct term?

Tags: word-choice, compound, place-name

Recently, I have come across the phrase *"am Oderstrand"* and saw it translated as *"on the banks of the Oder [River]."*

With that in mind, I am wondering if it can be used with other rivers. 
In my case, I am wondering if this word structure can be used with the *Red River*.

Just as an example, I am trying to say something along the lines of *"on the banks of the Red River."*
Would it then be correct to say *"am Rotenstrand"*?

I am aware 'der Strand' is the beach, but I have seen it used more like its synonym 'bank' or 'shore', words of the like.

Comment: What you can say though is _Roten Sand_ and then it becomes a nice Rammstein ballad

Answer (score 21):

You can say "Oderstrand" or "Rheinufer" because you would not say "Oder Fluss" or "Rhein Fluss".

The Red River (at least the one in Asia) is translated as "Roter Fluss" so you would have to say "am Ufer des Roten Flusses". You would only use "Strand" in this context if there actually was a beach on the river, i.e. the bank was sandy and flat.

"Rotenstrand" is not a word anybody would use. You could say "am roten Strand" if there was a red beach somewhere

Comment: I can't think of a river in Europe which has a *Fluss* added in German. Do you know an example?

Comment: @Janka: Die Wien (die in Wien in die Donau mündet) hat einen zweiten Namen, der sogar weitaus häufiger verwendet wird: Der [Wienfluss](https://www.wien.gv.at/wiki/index.php/Wienfluss).

Comment: @Janka: Sometimes *-strom* for very wide rivers (like Oderstrom, Elbstrom, Donaustrom) is appended.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das dürfte wohl mehr oder weniger nur landschaftlich bekannt sein, ich habe bislang noch nie vom "Wienfluss" gehört

Comment: @Clemens That's rather poetic or at least sublime language, not used in everyday life

Comment: @LarsBeck: Yes, sure I wouldn't normally use it either. But it's valid German and there are some exceptions. For instance *Altes Land am Elbstrom* is a fixed term that has nothing to do with poetry.

Comment: @LarsBeck: Aber möglicherweise hast du schon mal vom [**Theater an der Wien**](https://www.theater-wien.at/de/home) gehört. Es ist eines der drei Opernhäuser in Wien (andere: Staatsoper, Volksoper). Es steht direkt am Ufer des Wienflusses (also am Ufer der Wien) und hat seinen Namen von dieser Lage. Allerdings sieht man heute den Wienfluss an dieser Stelle nicht mehr, weil der Fluss dort mit großen Platten überdeckt ist, und sich heute darauf der [Naschmarkt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_Naschmarkt) befindet.

Comment: But you say Donaustrom or Rheinstrom. Whether or not there is a suffix has little to do with the importance of the river, I think.

Comment: @henning: But you won't append *-strom* to small rivers. For example *Paderstrom* or *Allerstrom* sounds very ironic because *Strom* describes a broad river.

Comment: @Janka You.re right of course. I removed that sentence

Comment: „Wo Werra sich und Fulda küssen / Sie ihren Namen büßen müssen / Und hier entsteht durch diesen Kuß / Deutsch bis zum Meer der Weserfluß“.

Answer (score 9):

It only works for rivers which don't need that *river* extension to be recognized.

So, *Oh London, du Zasterpfuhl am Themsestrand* (Oh London, you boodle puddle on Thames' banks) works, but for the *Red River*, regardless which one, it doesn't work. Because you cannot tell its name from that of the color Red.

This problem also arises in German. For example, there's the river *der Regen*, and the word *der Regen* (rain). You cannot tell those apart, so you wouldn't say *am Regenstrand*, because no one would understand you meant the banks of that river and not a beach in the rain.

Comment: If you live nearby the Regen river, I guess you could very well use "Regenufer" oder "Regenstrand" and everybody would understand what is meant. As so often, context is everything

Answer (score 4):

I think this is just a case of forming words from two parts (Komposition).

- https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_(Grammatik)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)

In the context of rivers there are indeed lots of variations all involving things usually to be found near rivers. Examples of such things may include *-wiesen, -niederungen, -aue, -wehr, -mündung, -delta, -promenade, -deich, -tal, -ufer, -strand*. (I'm sorry I can't provide translation for all of these.) Some made it even to city names, e.g., *Travemünde, Paderborn*.

Also you may find terms describing events or buildings or professions combined with names of rivers or seas or even oceans, e.g., *Elbphilharmonie, Elbhochwasser, Elbvertiefung, Nordseefischer, Atlantiküberquerung*.

As you can see, these are sometimes formed with a shortened form of the name of the water (*Elb-* vs. *Elbe*), and they appear a bit off when formed with names of two words, though people will still occasionally do it (e.g., *Steinhuder Meerufer*). And I can't remember a case where I've noticed a compound containing the english name of the river.

Also, most of these terms are known only in the region they appear, so most people may not recognize foreign sites at once (*Podelta*), others are however more common (*Amazonasdelta, Nildelta*).

---

In conclusion, I don't know what river you are actually talking about.

If it's original name is *Red River*, one might potentially *say* something like:

> Ich war im Urlaub am Red-River-Strand. (If there is such a thing)

But especially in written language you would most likely rather put it this way:

> Ich war im Urlaub am Ufer des Red River.

If it's [this Red River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_River_(Asia)) instead (original name in a language other than English), one would probably write *and* say the latter, but with the german name.

> ... am Ufer des Roten Flusses.

Unless you want to show-off you knowing the name in the local language (Vietnamese/Chinese?), in which case you would use that name.

In any case you should take care to provide more context to make sure people know what river you are actually talking about.

Comment: "Steinhuder Meerufer" is ungrammatical. Correct would be "Steinhuder-Meer-Ufer", although unusual indeed. And if someone wanted to create a stereotypical German word, they could say "am Roter-Fluss-Strand".

Comment: @xehpuk Thank you for your input. I put more of a focus on actual usage and aesthetics than on grammatical correctness. And while _Steinhuder-Meer-Ufer_ and _Roter-Fluss-Strand_ may be correct grammatically (I'm not sure about that), both lack any measure of style in both spoken and written German.

Comment: @xehpuk: "'Steinhuder Meerufer' is ungrammatical." - I disagree. However, it is not the bank of the Steinhuder Meer, but the bank of an unspecified sea in or near Steinhude.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This would be called "Steinhuder Meer**es**ufer".

Comment: @xehpuk: While that is the more usual form, it seems that [*Meerufer* is or was in use, as well](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Meeresufer%2CMeerufer&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMeeresufer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMeerufer%3B%2Cc0). And while ngram shows the results from literature, I would bet that the less "elaborate" form (Meerufer) is actually not that rare in comparison in spoken language.